# To display a custom view on top of the marker

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

after tap to marker how to display `CustomCalloutView` on top of the marker?

deal in this method:

```
func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedRect: CGRect, animated: Bool) {

    if isCalloutTappable() {
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(calloutTapped))
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    } else {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    //Always, Slightly above center
    self.center = view.center.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.frame.height))
    view.addSubview(self)

}
```

How to pass a marker frame to it?

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you try these [instructions](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/custom-callout/)?

Comment: @Isuru yes, I try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

in `CustomCalloutView`

```
var annotationPoint: CGPoint

required init(annotation: CustomAnnotation, annotationPoint: CGPoint) {
    self.representedObject = annotation
    self.annotationPoint = annotationPoint
}


func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedRect: CGRect, animated: Bool) {

    self.center = annotationPoint.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.frame.height - 40.0))

    view.addSubview(self)

}
```

in `MapVC`:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, calloutViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLCalloutView? {        
    let customAnnotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate, title: title, subtitle: subtitle, image: img!)

    let annotationPoint = mapView.convert(annotation.coordinate, toPointTo: nil)
    return CustomCalloutView(annotation: customAnnotation, annotationPoint: annotationPoint)
 }
```